# Magick++ Unable to read file, C++ Win32

Tags: visual-c++, magick++

I have tried to use Magick++. I tried to load an Image with it but it fails

```
        void mPDF::addImage(std::string path, unsigned int x, unsigned int y)
    {
         Magick::InitializeMagick("C:\\CommonFiles\\GraphicsMagick\\");
//with or without the ending two \\ same results
        Magick::Image img;
        try
        {
            img.read("c:\\temp\\Moon.jpg");
        }
        catch (Magick::ErrorBlob p)
        {
            std::cout << "Folder: " << path << std::endl;
            std::cout << p.what() << std::endl;
            system("pause");
            exit(1);
        }
        Magick::Geometry tmp  = img.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < tmp.height(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < tmp.width(); j++)
            {
                Magick::Color col = img.pixelColor(i, j);
                this->p.setLineColor(col.redQuantum(), col.greenQuantum(), col.blueQuantum());
                this->p.drawLine(x + j, y - i, x + j, y - i);
            }
        }
    }
```

it throws an exception that he can't load the file. It says : unable to open Image '³.0': No such File or directory. In Magick++ Documentation it is written like I used it.

Can someone help me?

Comment: 1st: nearly unused variable `path` (only in `catch`); 2nd: does 'C:\\temp\\Moon.jpg' exist?

Comment: normally the string path should be in img.read(path). but I removed it for testing. yes c:\temp\Moon.jpg exist

Comment: if your error message is correct, it should not be from your `catch`block ... maybe it throws on `Magick::InitializeMagick("C:\\CommonFiles\\GraphicsMagick\\");`?

Comment: I made try{ Magick::InitializeMagick("C:\\CommonFiles\\GraphicsMagick"); }
 catch (Magick::ErrorBlob e)
 {
  std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
 }
 the same error

Comment: can it read as `img.read("Moon.jpg");` ?

Comment: The solution to your problem is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23684903/imagemagick-error-unable-to-open-image