# ImageMagick Error: Unable to open image

Tags: c++, string, imagemagick, magick++

I'm using ImageMagick (Magick++) in my application but when trying to load an image I get the error:

`Unable to open image '??': Invalid argument @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2657`

From reading other peoples problems online `??` is typically the file trying to be loaded, and I am obviously not passing the file location `??` to the loader - so it appears not to be able to resolve the string I am giving it. Tried using Unicode and Multi-byte. Copied project settings from example(s). File definitely exists and definitely the correct location.

**Code:**

```
LawlessFBXTexture* LawlessFBXTextureManager::CreateTexture(std::string pFullFilePath) 
{
    Magick::Image* img = nullptr;
    Magick::Blob blob;

    try
    {
        img = new Magick::Image();
        img->read(pFullFilePath);
        img->write(&blob, "RGBA");
    }
    catch (Magick::Error& Err)
    {
        std::string errstr = Err.what();
        std::wstring stemps = std::wstring(errstr.begin(), errstr.end());
        LPCWSTR sws = stemps.c_str();
        OutputDebugString(L"FBXSDK: ERROR: ");
        OutputDebugString(sws);
        OutputDebugString(L"\n");

        int ImageNotFound = 0;      /// Image Not found <---
        assert(ImageNotFound);
    }

    LawlessFBXTexture* tex = new LawlessFBXTexture();

    glGenTextures(1, &tex->TextureBuffer);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex->TextureBuffer);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, img->columns(), img->rows(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, blob.data());
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    return tex;
}
```

**being called by :**

`LawlessFBXTexture* tex = CreateTexture("..\\..\\Asset\\Models\\LawlessCoreAsset\\DEFAULT_DIFFUSE.png");`

Comment: Please provide a complete example. If I should guess, the problem is that somewhere you are mixing wchar_t and char (WCHAR and CHAR in MS Windows) and simply brute-force casting between different pointer types. To clarify, the problem is probably in the code calling this function. BTW: It could also be the case that the file is not found under the given relative path, because the current dir isn't the one you think...

Comment: The calling code is shown above 

"LawlessFBXTexture* tex = CreateTexture("..\\..\\Asset\\Models\\LawlessCoreAsset\\DEFAULT_DIFFUSE.png");"

and the relative path is fine, I have tried loading the file with fstream and it works.

Comment: Try passing `pFullFilePath` to `GetFullPathName` or `realpath`.

Comment: Did you call `InitializeMagick(*argv);` anywhere?

Comment: Yeah I've called that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed this works fine in release mode, without making changes. I am pretty sure this is down to a bug so I'll post my findings on the Magick forums.

Comment: Reporting from 2018, this is still very much the case, at least on my Windows 10 build using version 7.0.7. Thankfully I finally stumbled on your answer, because it's taken me at least several hours to figure this out...

Comment: Update: Because this was never answered in full, I'm going to leave another answer that solves the issue properly. TLDR; it's not a bug, there's just some configuration needed first.

Answer (score 1):

So, after taking the OP's advice and setting my project to release mode, everything worked perfectly. That said, I very quickly realized that there is a VERY good reason for Debug mode to exist. Writing code for a program that doesn't give run-time error messages is an absolute pain in the *** to do. Not to mention all of your favorite conveniences like breakpoints, assertions, and such are gone.

Turns out, despite offering multiple binary distributions for each platform, there are no developer binaries available at all. By which I mean, if you want to be able to debug your program while using the Magick++ libraries, you MUST compile your DLLs from source (using the debug configuration to compile those DLLs). Only then can you use the Debug compilation mode for your projects which link against it.

Here's [the thread](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=13970) I found that discusses this. Note that in the thread it says to build static libs, but this is obviously not necessary, and it's probably more convenient to build using the dynamic libraries option.

Anyway, if you follow the steps enumerated in the link I provide, you should finally be able to debug your Magick++ program without pulling your hair out :)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, *Magick++* on Visual Studio does not like the /MTd option

```
  Configuration Properties->C++->Code Generation->Runtime Library
    Setting
```

it on /MT should work fine.

Comment: On my Vista x64 (VS 2010) /MT causes delete image; to crash, works fine with /MD though